# How to find and copy specific content from a word document and past it in another document using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have recorded a macro to extract a specific content from one word document to another, but its limited. I need to extract all the selected content into new document and save it with suffix or prefix the word "glos" in the same file name.

Since, the document name is in active state, did not use the macros for another document and even if changed the file name in the macros, it will extract the contents till the recorded count in macros.

Finding the specified content using the regex `"\<(MN_GLOS)\>(*)\</(\1)\>"`.

Input:

```
    <CHAP_NUM>01</CHAP_NUM>
    <CHAP_TL> Lorem Ipsum</CHAP_TL>

    <PARA>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</PARA>
    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>

    <PARA>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</PARA>

    <PARA>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</PARA>

    <PARA>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</PARA>

    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>

    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>

    <PARA>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</PARA>

    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>
```

**Macro**

```
    Sub Macro5()
    '
    ' Macro5 Macro
    '
    '
        selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With selection.Find
            .Text = "\<(MN_GLOS)\>(*)\</(\1)\>"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        selection.Find.Execute
        selection.Copy
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
        selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("ca_ch01__studyingsexlty_24feb2018CE_QA.doc [Compatibility Mode]") _
            .Activate
        Application.Browser.Next
        selection.Copy
        Windows("Doc1.docx").Activate
        selection.PasteAndFormat (wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery)
    End Sub
```

**Output (new docx)**

```
    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>
    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>
    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>
    <MN_GLOS>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
    </MN_GLOS>
```

Please help me to extract the content to new document.

Comment: What you want isn't clear. The code you show doesn't perform any search (Find) and since you don't describe what this macro is doing and HOW it's "not working" it's a bit difficult to know where to start helping you. Try recording a macro using Word's (advanced) Find functionality to perform the basic search. Then look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49014520/3077495 for how to do multiple searches with intervening actions. It's just one of hundreds of examples of this kind of thing.

Comment: @Cindy Meister, thanks for your response, actually i'm a beginner to vba. here i need to export the specific content to new word document. just i have find `"\<MN_GLOS\>([!""]*)?\<\/MN_GLOS\>"` & copy the content and paste it in an another document, this process should be repeated until end.