# Assign .Find results to a variable or write it directly into the cell?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a problem with assigning .Find results to a variable or writing it directly into the Excel cell.

The macro (that's written and lunched from Excel) cycles through 2-5 paragraphs with customers data (in word document) - 1 customer data in every single paragraph.

When macro separates a single paragraph it then searches for info (ID number) in this paragraph only.
The search is performed using word wildcards <[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{6}> and ID number is always found.
After it's found I need to write it into `ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 12)`
Or I just need to assign it to a variable, but I don't know how to do this.

```
For Each Para In rng.Paragraphs
            'get NAME
            name = Trim$(Para.Range.Words(3))    'Trim$ is the string version. Use this if you are using it on a string.
            Debug.Print name
            pStart = InStr(1, Para, ".") + 1      'here we get 3     'we should get 3
            Length = InStr(1, Para, ",") - pStart  'here we get 22/29/27/39 - 3
            'exit For Each loop when coma character is not found
            If Length < 1 Then Exit For
            Debug.Print Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            name = Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            'get PESEL
            pStart = InStr(1, Para, textToFind4) + Len(textToFind4) + 1       'textToFind4 = "PESEL"
            Length = InStr(pStart, Para, ",") - pStart  '51-pStart = 11
            Debug.Print Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            pesel = Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            
            sexDigit = Mid(pesel, 10, 1)
            Debug.Print sexDigit
            remainder = sexDigit Mod 2
            Debug.Print remainder
            
            x = x + 1
            'Cells(x, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value = name
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value = pesel
            
            Set singleParaRng = Para.Range
            Debug.Print singleParaRng
            
            'Check if there is an ID Card and find its number
            If remainder = 0 Then
                  'With singleParaRng.Find
                   With Para.Range.Find
                   .Text = "legitymująca się dowodem osobistym"
                   .MatchWildcards = False
                   .MatchCase = False
                   .Forward = True
                   .Execute
                     If .Found = True Then
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "dowód"
                        With Para.Range.Find
                         .Text = "<[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{6}>"
                         .MatchWildcards = True
                         .MatchCase = True
                         .Wrap = wdFindStop
                         .Forward = True
                         .Execute
                           If .Found = True Then      'here is the problem
                              ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 12) = Para.Range.Text     'here is the problem
                           End If
                        End With
                     Else
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "paszport"
                     End If
                  End With
            Else
                  'With singleParaRng.Find
                   With Para.Range.Find
                   .Text = "legitymujący się dowodem osobistym"
                   .MatchWildcards = False
                   .MatchCase = False
                   .Forward = True
                   .Execute
                     If .Found = True Then
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "dowód"
                     Else
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "paszport"
                     End If
                  End With
            End If
               
               
 Next Para
```

Currently the result is that the whole paragraph is written into the `ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 12)` cell and I just need this wildcard `ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 12)` result written in.
Or assigned into a variable.

I've read this thread [MS Word VBA Find and Loop (NOT Replace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014170/ms-word-vba-find-and-loop-not-replace?rq=1)
and I think the answer is somewhere there, but I can't figure it out for my own example.

Comment: So is this macro in your Excel or are you triggering a word macro from excel?

Comment: The macro is written in and lunched from Excel and it works on Word file. All the ```Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")``` and ```Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")``` and ```Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument``` and ```Set mySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet``` is put in place - no mistake in the beginning of this macro.

Comment: Why not just [create an array](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/) to store the info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually - checked and working code below:

```
Sub FindNamesPESELsAndPriceWithInput_Finalll()          'this code works flawlessly
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application              'it is assigned to button #2
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document                 '[0-9]{1;5}[ ]{1;2}/[0-9]{4}
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim idNmbr As Word.Range
    Dim singleParaRng As Word.Range
    Dim fullName As Word.Range
    
    Dim pStart As Long
    Dim pEnd As Long
    Dim Length As Long
    Dim textToFind1 As String
    Dim textToFind2 As String
    Dim textToFind3 As String
    Dim textToFind4 As String
    Dim textToFind5 As String
    Dim textToFind6 As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim pesel As String
    Dim sexDigit As String
    Dim price As Double      'Dim price As Single    'Dim price As Long
    Dim remainder As Integer
    
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long
    Dim parNmbr As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim scndRng As Range
    
    Dim aryNum As Variant
    
        
    'Assigning object variables and values
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")       'At its simplest, CreateObject creates an instance of an object,
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")     'whereas GetObject gets an existing instance of an object.
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set mySheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Set MySheet = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    Set rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    Set scndRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J40").Find("cena", , xlValues)
    textToFind1 = "KRS 0000511671, REGON: 147269372, NIP: 5252588142," ' "KRS 0000609737, REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"    ' "REGON 364061169, NIP 951-24-09-783,"
    textToFind2 = "- ad."        'w umowach deweloperskich FW2 było "- ad."
    textToFind3 = "Tożsamość stawających"
    textToFind4 = "PESEL"
    textToFind5 = "cenę brutto w kwocie łącznej"
    textToFind6 = "cenę brutto w kwocie "
    x = 11
    
    'InStr function returns a Variant (Long) specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.
    startPos = InStr(1, rng, textToFind1) - 1    'here we get 1410 or 1439 or 1555, we're looking 4 "TextToFind1"
    endPos = InStr(1, rng, textToFind2) - 1      'here we get 2315 or 2595 or 2207, we're looking 4 "- ad."
    
    parNmbr = rng.Paragraphs.Count
    Debug.Print "Total # of paragraphs = " & parNmbr
    
    'Calibrating the range from which the names will be pulled
        If startPos > 1 And endPos > 1 Then                                ' Exit Sub
            rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos                      ' startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Or endPos = -1
            Debug.Print "Paragraphs.Count = " & rng.Paragraphs.Count
            Debug.Print rng
            rng.MoveStart wdParagraph, 1                                   ' Moves the start position of the specified range.
            Debug.Print "Paragraphs.Count = " & rng.Paragraphs.Count
            Debug.Print rng
        Else
            endPos = InStr(1, rng, textToFind3) - 1 'here we get 2595 lub 2207, we're looking 4 "Tożsamość stawających"
            rng.SetRange Start:=startPos, End:=endPos                                  'startPos = 0 Or endPos = 0 Or endPos = -1
            Debug.Print "Paragraphs.Count = " & rng.Paragraphs.Count
            Debug.Print rng
            rng.MoveStart wdParagraph, 1
            rng.MoveEnd wdParagraph, -1
            Debug.Print "Paragraphs.Count = " & rng.Paragraphs.Count
            Debug.Print rng
        End If
        
    
    If startPos <= 0 Or endPos <= 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Client's names were not found!")
    'Client's names input
    Else
        For Each Para In rng.Paragraphs
            'get NAME
            name = Trim$(Para.Range.Words(3))    'Trim$ is the string version. Use this if you are using it on a string.
            Debug.Print name
            pStart = InStr(1, Para, ".") + 1      'here we get 3     'we should get 3
            Length = InStr(1, Para, ",") - pStart  'here we get 22/29/27/39 - 3
            'exit For Each loop when coma character is not found
            If Length < 1 Then Exit For
            Debug.Print Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            name = Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            'get PESEL
            pStart = InStr(1, Para, textToFind4) + Len(textToFind4) + 1       'textToFind4 = "PESEL"
            Length = InStr(pStart, Para, ",") - pStart  '51-pStart = 11
            Debug.Print Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            pesel = Trim$(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            
            sexDigit = Mid(pesel, 10, 1)
            Debug.Print sexDigit
            remainder = sexDigit Mod 2
            Debug.Print remainder
            
            x = x + 1
            'Cells(x, 1).Value = Trim(Mid(Para, pStart, Length))
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value = name
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value = pesel
            
            Set singleParaRng = Para.Range
            Debug.Print singleParaRng
            Set idNmbr = Para.Range
            Debug.Print idNmbr
            
            'Check if there is an ID Card and find its number
            If remainder = 0 Then
                   With Para.Range.Find
                   .Text = "legitymująca się dowodem osobistym"
                   .MatchWildcards = False
                   .MatchCase = False
                   .Forward = True
                   .Execute
                     If .Found = True Then
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "dowodem osobistym"
                        Debug.Print Para.Range.Text      'Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
                        With idNmbr.Find                 'Dim idNmbr As Word.Range
                         .Text = "<[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{6}>"
                         .MatchWildcards = True
                         .MatchCase = True
                         .Wrap = wdFindStop
                         .Forward = True
                         .Execute
                         Debug.Print idNmbr
                            If .Found = True Then
                               mySheet.Cells(x, 12) = idNmbr
                            End If
                         End With
                     Else
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "paszportem"
                     End If
                  End With
            Else
                   With Para.Range.Find
                   .Text = "legitymujący się dowodem osobistym"
                   .MatchWildcards = False
                   .MatchCase = False
                   .Forward = True
                   .Execute
                     If .Found = True Then
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "dowodem osobistym"
                        Debug.Print Para.Range.Text      'Dim Para As Word.Paragraph
                        With idNmbr.Find                 'Dim idNmbr As Word.Range
                         .Text = "<[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{6}>"
                         .MatchWildcards = True
                         .MatchCase = True
                         .Wrap = wdFindStop
                         .Forward = True
                         .Execute
                         Debug.Print idNmbr
                            If .Found = True Then
                               mySheet.Cells(x, 12) = idNmbr
                            End If
                         End With
                     Else
                        mySheet.Cells(x, 11) = "paszportem"
                     End If
                  End With
            End If
               
        Next Para
 'End of client's names input
```

The main change comparing to the code in the question is adding a variable to store .Find result (in the very beginning of the macro).

```
Dim idNmbr As Word.Range
```

Second thing is assigning this object variable a value in this line and checking it's value using  `Debug.Print` command.

```
Set idNmbr = Para.Range
Debug.Print idNmbr
```

Having previous declarations and assignments in place I perform .Find as follows:

```
With idNmbr.Find                    'Dim idNmbr As Word.Range
    .Text = "<[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{6}>"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Forward = True
    .Execute
Debug.Print idNmbr
```

After checking the .Find result with `Debug.Print idNmbr` I know if I have what I expected or not.

The last two lines assign .Find results to the desired Excel cell:

```
   If .Found = True Then
      mySheet.Cells(x, 12) = idNmbr
   End If
End With
```

Comment: Could you clarify this answer? If someone has a similar problem, this code dump is unlikely to help.  Can you keep the relevant parts of the code/changes only, or, at least explain what the fix was?  Thank you!