# VBA for ms-WORD - Adding phonetic guide with VBA on all word instance based on list of pair

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a pair of words shown below, and I would like to use VBA to automatically add the number as the phonetic guide for all instance on the word document based on the list. I tried using the [range method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Range.PhoneticGuide) but I couldn't figure out since I am still new to VBA.

Below is and example:

- Sentence: I left a very demanding job in management consulting
- word pair: I-100, left-283, a-8, demanding-920

Result I am trying to get

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Secondly, your question lacks the focus usually required here as it sort of falls into the category of "I have an idea but don't know how to code, can someone do it for me?"

However, as your question relates to something that I have never needed to do in over 30 years of coding with Word I find it interesting enough to warrant bending a few rules.

The first problem you need to solve is how you store the value pairs and loop through them to retrieve them. I am going to leave that for you to solve. There are plenty of examples on the internet to help you with this.

The next part is to find the text in the document and add the phonetic guides. For this you can use the `Find` method. You can find a good example of using this in the answer to the question [MS Word VBA Find and Loop (NOT Replace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014170/ms-word-vba-find-and-loop-not-replace?rq=1)

When used with the `Selection` object `Find` will select the found text, if there is any. Similarly, when used with a `Range` if `Find` is successful it will redefine the range to the found text. You can use this behavior to add your phonetic guide.

I have provided you with a basic routine that will do this and an example of usage.

```
Sub TestAddPhoneticGuideToText()
  AddPhoneticGuideToText ActiveDocument, "I ", "100"
  AddPhoneticGuideToText ActiveDocument, "left", "283"
  AddPhoneticGuideToText ActiveDocument, " a ", "8"
  AddPhoneticGuideToText ActiveDocument, "demanding", "920"
End Sub

Sub AddPhoneticGuideToText(docTarget As Document, findText As String, phoneticText As String)
  Dim searchRange As Word.Range
  Dim textFound As Boolean

  Set searchRange = docTarget.Range

  With searchRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .text = findText
    textFound = .Execute(Forward:=True)

    Do While textFound = True
      searchRange.phoneticGuide text:=phoneticText, Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentCenter, Raise:=11, FontSize:=7
      searchRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'search from after the found to the end of the doc
      textFound = .Execute(Forward:=True)
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Timothy. Thank you very much for the advise.

Comment: Hi Timothy. Thank you very much for the advise. Sorry, I understand what you're saying. I will try to avoid in the future. I have posted this on freelancer websites as well but I wasn't able to find someone who could help me.... I tried looking for about 6 hours at least and I still couldn't figure it out. Thank you very much. I will work to modify the code as well.