# How can I get all values of found results from VBA Find?

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

I’m writing a macro that is supposed to print all found values to a text file. So far I got the find macro, couldn’t find the part where I can get each value of each found result.

```
Sub ReplaceAndWrite()

Dim TextFile As Integer

Dim FilePath As String

Dim FileName As String

 FileName = ActiveDocument.Name

FilePath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & FileName & ".txt"

TextFile = FreeFile

Open FiledPath For Output As TextFile

With ActiveDocument.Range

With .Find

  .ClearFormatting

  .Replacement.ClearFormatting

  .Text = "(#VL-*>) <[! ,^13]@#"

  .ReplacementText = "\1"

  .Forward = True

  .Wrap = wdFindContinue

  .Format = False

  .MatchWildcards = True

  With .Replacement

   .ClearFormatting

   .Font.Bold = True

   .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue

   .Font.Underline = True

   .Font.AllCaps = True

  End With

.MatchCase = False

.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With

End With

Close TextFile

End Sub
```

How fo I write the found results to the text file?
Is it possible to loop through all the results and write their values to the text file?
Is there a better way to accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Cindy Meister's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49014520/4717755) to a similar question as a foundation, the following code is presented as an example.

The main concept here is to make sure that a match for your search text has been found (`foundAnotherMatch`) and also to keep track of the position at which the first match was found (`firstFoundPosition = searchRng.Start`). With these in mind, you can loop through every occurrence in your document and then stop searching when you've reached the end (actually, when you wrap around and get back to the first occurrence again).

Writing the text you've found happens with each of the occurrences as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceAndWrite()
    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveDocument.Name
    FilePath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & FileName & ".txt"
    TextFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Output As TextFile
    
    Dim thisDoc As Range
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Set thisDoc = ActiveDocument.Range
    Set searchRng = thisDoc.Duplicate
    
    With searchRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(#VL-*>) <[! ,^13]@#"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
            With .Replacement
                .ClearFormatting
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
                .Font.Underline = True
                .Font.AllCaps = True
            End With
        .MatchCase = False
        
        Dim foundAnotherMatch As Boolean
        Dim firstFoundPosition As Long
        foundAnotherMatch = .Execute
        
        Do While foundAnotherMatch
            Dim foundText As String
            foundText = searchRng.Text
            If firstFoundPosition = 0 Then
                '--- save the location of the first occurrence of the text
                firstFoundPosition = searchRng.Start
            ElseIf firstFoundPosition = searchRng.Start Then
                '--- we're back at the first position (wrapped from the
                '    end of the document), so exit
                Exit Do
            End If
            
            Write #TextFile, foundText
            
            searchRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            foundAnotherMatch = .Execute(Forward:=True)
        Loop
    End With
   
    Close TextFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst your answer is along the right lines it needs some improvement. `thisDoc` is unnecessary and should be removed. Instead use `Set searchRng = ActiveDocument.Range`. Using `.Wrap = wdFindStop` renders `firstFoundPosition` obsolete and removes the need for the `If ... ElseIf` in the loop. Using `Do While .Execute` removes the need for `foundAnotherMatch` and `foundAnotherMatch = .Execute(Forward:=True)`

Comment: Though the answer is printing the requested values to the text file, it does not perform all the desired replacements.

Comment: @Judah if that's the case, then your original question was not clear in exactly what pattern you are trying to `Find` and what is the required `Replacement.Text`. Both of those values were used from your post. Please update your question with examples of text that should be replaced and what is the intended replacement. My example code replaced all strings in a sample that I generated, but we can help you better if you can provide a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrOut As String, DocTgt As Document
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "(#[Vv][Ll]-*>) <[! ,^13]@#"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    StrOut = StrOut & .Text & vbCr
    .Text = Split(.Text, " ")(0)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
  Set DocTgt = Documents.Add
  DocTgt.Range.Text = StrOut
  DocTgt.SaveAs2 FileName:=Split(.FullName, ".doc")(0) & ".txt", _
    Fileformat:=wdFormatText, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  DocTgt.Close False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Found & Saved:" & vbCr & StrOut
End Sub
```

It's not clear whether you want to find upper-case strings, or lower-case strings - your other thread implied the latter. Accordingly I've modified the Find expression to find either.

It's not clear whether you want to output the entire found string, or just the retained bit. If it's just the latter, swap the order of:

```
    StrOut = StrOut & .Text & vbCr
    .Text = Split(.Text, " ")(0)
```