# Find Acronyms in Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a VBA macro to extract the acronyms in a Word Document.  The Acronyms will always be found in parenthesis with their definitions preceding them.  Like: Acronym Finder Tool (AFT)

I have written the following but cannot get it to work. I get a type mismatch error on this line:

```
' Find all matches of the updated acronym pattern
    Set AcronymMatches = SearchRange.Find.Execute(FindText:=AcronymPattern, MatchWildcards:=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub ExtractAcronymsAndDefinitions2()
    Dim SourceDoc As Document
    Dim DestinationDoc As Document
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim AcronymPattern As String
    Dim AcronymMatches As Object
    Dim Match As Variant
    
    ' Set the source document (the active document)
    Set SourceDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Create a new blank document for the extracted content
    Set DestinationDoc = Documents.Add(DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument)
    
    ' Define a more inclusive acronym pattern (including lowercase and digits)
    'AcronymPattern = "\([A-Z]{2,}\)"
    'AcronymPattern = "\([A-Za-z0-9]+\)"
    AcronymPattern = "\([a-zA-Z-&]{2,}\)"


    ' Set the search range to the entire source document
    'Set SearchRange = SourceDoc.Range
    Set SearchRange = SourceDoc.Content
    
    ' Find all matches of the updated acronym pattern
    Set AcronymMatches = SearchRange.Find.Execute(FindText:=AcronymPattern, MatchWildcards:=True)
      'With SearchRange.Find
      '   .ClearFormatting
      '   .Text = AcronymPattern
      '   .Replacement.Text = ""
      '   .Forward = True
      '   .Wrap = wdFindStop
      '   .Format = False
      '   .MatchCase = False
      '   .MatchAllWordForms = False
      '   .MatchSoundsLike = False
      '   .MatchWildcards = True
      ' While .Execute
      '  Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.Text = Documents(DestinationDoc$).Range.Text + SearchRange.Text
      ' Wend
     ' End With
    
    ' Loop through each match and extract the definition
    For Each Match In AcronymMatches
        Dim Definition As String
        Definition = Trim(Left(Match.Parent.Text, Match.Start - 1))
        
        ' Extract the entire acronym (including parentheses)
        Dim FullAcronym As String
        FullAcronym = Match.Text
        
        ' Remove parentheses from the full acronym
        Dim CleanAcronym As String
        CleanAcronym = Replace(FullAcronym, "(", "")
        CleanAcronym = Replace(CleanAcronym, ")", "")
        
        ' Count the number of letters in the cleaned acronym
        Dim AcronymLength As Integer
        AcronymLength = Len(CleanAcronym)
        
        ' Find the specified number of words preceding the opening parenthesis
        Dim WordsToCopy As String
        WordsToCopy = Left(Match.Parent.Words.Last.Previous.Text, AcronymLength)
        
        ' Append to the destination document
        DestinationDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Acronym: " & FullAcronym & vbTab & "Definition: " & Definition & vbTab & "Words: " & WordsToCopy & vbCrLf
    Next Match
    
    ' Save and display the new document
    DestinationDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:="Extracted_Acronyms.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
    DestinationDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox "Acronyms and definitions extracted successfully!"
End Sub
```

The macro aims to extract acronyms within parentheses from the active Word document, along with their definitions (the text preceding the opening parenthesis), and paste this information into a new document.

Comment: The `Find.Execute`  method returns a Boolean, not a collection of matches. 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66627543/478884 for how to use `Find` in a loop.

Comment: What's the expected output for `Acronym Finder Tool (AFT)`? Is there more than one definition+Acronyms in  a praragraph?

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42313-acronym-definiton-list-generator.html